# Android: IntentService getting Result back to ListFragment

Tags: android, sqlite, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, intentservice

I built a fully-functioning **FragmentActivity** based on this [demo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentStatePagerSupport.java).

Originally (like other activities in my app) the data was being loaded into the **FragmentActivity.ListFragment.ListView** from SQLite in the UI thread.

I have successfully converted two other activities (not fragment- or list-activities) to a **ResultReceiver** paradigm that uses an **IntentService** to get the data from SQLite. The obvious difference in this instance is the fact that the custom **ResultReceiver** is declared in the **ListFragment**, not the **FragmentActivity**:

```
public EWTRReceiver ArrayListFragmentReceiver;
```

**PROBLEM:** The **IntentService** gets the request, pulls the data but is NOT able to get the data back to the **ListFragment**: NullPointerException on this line in IntentService.rspPlayers():

```
r.send(mSignal, resultData);
```

I'm convinced that I'm missing something simple that will make me feel like an idiot...i just need to be pushed in the right direction.

Following is (1) the call from the **ListFragment** to the **IntenService**, (2) the onHandleIntent of the **IntentService** and (3) the method in the **IntentService** that calls back to the **ListFragment** (rspPlayers()).

Thanks!

FragmentActivity.ListFragment.callCtlr():

```
    private void callCtlr(int mSignal){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG_FRGACTPLAYERS, "ArrayListFragment.callCtlr() called with signal: "+mSignal);
        }
        /** Intent to transmit between processes */
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CtlPlayers.class);
        // declare Source of Signal
        intent.putExtra("Source", ArrayListFragmentReceiver);
        /** process signal to send to CtlPlayers */
        switch (mSignal){
           case Constants.S_DB_READPLYRLDR:
               if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                   Log.i(Constants.TAG_FRGACTPLAYERS, "ArrayListFragment.callCtlr(S_DB_READPLYRLDR) to CtlPlayers.");
               }
               // Send CtlAlliances the request for the list of Alliances in current Sector
               intent.putExtra("CurrentSector", this.getArguments().getString("FSECTR"));
               intent.putExtra("CurrentAlliance", this.getArguments().getString("FANAME"));
               intent.putExtra("signal", Constants.S_DB_READPLYRLDR);
               break;
          case Constants.S_DB_READPLYRREC:
               if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                   Log.i(Constants.TAG_FRGACTPLAYERS, "ArrayListFragment.callCtlr(S_DB_READPLYRREC) to CtlPlayers.");
               }
               // Send CtlAlliances the request for the list of Alliances in current Sector
               intent.putExtra("CurrentSector", this.getArguments().getString("FSECTR"));
               intent.putExtra("CurrentAlliance", this.getArguments().getString("FANAME"));
               intent.putExtra("signal", Constants.S_DB_READPLYRREC);
               break;
            default:
                //do nothing
                break;
        }
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }
```

IntentService.onHandleIntent():

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intentREQ) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(Intent intent) called.");
    }
    /** get the receiver and bundle from the incoming Intent */
    ResultReceiver rInComing = intentREQ.getParcelableExtra("Source");

    /** get the bundle from the incoming Intent */
    extras = intentREQ.getExtras();
    /** variable to convey results to ActDlgAddPlyr */
    boolean mAnswer = false;
    /** tracks ActSector's context */
    Context mCtx    = getApplicationContext();
    int     mSignal = intentREQ.getIntExtra("signal", Constants.R_NO_SIGNAL);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "Signal Received = " + mSignal);
    }

    switch (mSignal) {
    case Constants.R_NO_SIGNAL :
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): NO READABLE SIGNAL WAS RECEIVED!");
        }
        break;
    case Constants.S_DB_ADDPLYR :
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): S_DB_ADDPLYR received.");
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            // Get the New Sector Name from the bundle
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): S_DB_ADDPLYR received with New Player.");
            }
            mAnswer = addNewPlayer(mCtx, extras);
            rspPlayers(Constants.R_DB_ADDPLYR, mAnswer, rInComing);
        }
        break;
    case Constants.S_DB_READPLYRLDR :
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): S_DB_READPLYRLDR received.");
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            // Get the New Sector Name from the bundle
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): S_DB_READPLYRLDR received.");
            }
            mAnswer = readPlyrLdr(mCtx, extras);
            rspPlayers(Constants.R_DB_READPLYRLDR, mAnswer, rInComing);
        }
        break;
    case Constants.S_DB_READPLYRREC :
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): S_DB_READPLYRREC received.");
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            // Get the New Sector Name from the bundle
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "onHandleIntent(): S_DB_READPLYRREC received.");
            }
            mAnswer = readPlyrRec(mCtx, extras);
            rspPlayers(Constants.R_DB_READPLYRREC, mAnswer, rInComing);
        }
        break;
    } // end switch
}
```

IntentService.rspPlayers() [sends result back to FragmentActivity.ListFragment]:

```
private void rspPlayers(int mSignal, boolean mCode, ResultReceiver r) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "respPlayers() called with signal, code: "+mSignal+", "+mCode);
    }

    Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
    switch (mSignal) {
    case Constants.R_DB_ADDPLYR :
        if (mCode == true) {
            resultData.putInt("reqStatus", Constants.R_TRUE_THAT);
        } else {
            resultData.putInt("reqStatus", Constants.R_NO_WAY);
        }
        break;
    case Constants.R_DB_READPLYRLDR :
        if (mCode == true) {
            resultData.putInt("reqStatus", Constants.R_TRUE_THAT);
            resultData.putInt("NumLdrRows", NumLdrRows);
            resultData.putSerializable("LPlyrList", LPlyrArray);
        } else {
            resultData.putInt("reqStatus",  Constants.R_NO_WAY);
        }
        break;
    case Constants.R_DB_READPLYRREC :
        if (mCode == true) {
            resultData.putInt("reqStatus", Constants.R_TRUE_THAT);
            resultData.putInt("NumRecRows", NumRecRows);
            resultData.putSerializable("RPlyrList", RPlyrArray);
        } else {
            resultData.putInt("reqStatus",  Constants.R_NO_WAY);
        }
        break;
    default :
        // do nothing
        break;
    }

    try {
        r.send(mSignal, resultData);
    } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "rspPlayers(): Exception message: "+e.getMessage());
        Log.e(Constants.TAG_CTLPLAYERS, "rspPlayers(): Exception cause: "+e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `ArrayListFragmentReceiver` is null.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
public EWTRReceiver ArrayListFragmentReceiver = new ResultReceiver(handler)
```

The handler is needed to make sure the response comes back in the original thread. This would be the next crash otherwise.

Check this tutorial for a sample implementation:

http://ramdroid.github.io/androiddev/ResultReceiverDemo.html

Comment: the line that stands out in my mind is "Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CtlPlayers.class);" in ArrayListFragment.callCtlr(). Maybe my IntentService is sending the result back to the FragmentActivity instead of the ListFragment...?

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT! I never put this in the fragment's onCreate(): 
        /** instantiate ResultReceiver to receive message from CtlSectors to this.onReceiverResult */
        ActSectorsReceiver = new EWTRReceiver(new Handler());
        ActSectorsReceiver.setReceiver(this);